# How to send multiple latitudes and longitudes in one hit for draw path using googleapis

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to draw a path between Latitudes and Longitudes I have many locations every time I am sending the location to this function and getting URL and then I call async task and one by one path is drawing.

Is there any way that I can send my all the latitudes and longitudes at the same time and draw path same as this drawing.

I am using this approach to draw path:-

```
 String GetUrl = makeURL(StartLatitude, StartLongitude, Latitude, Longitude);



public String makeURL(double sourcelat, double sourcelog, double destlat, double destlog) {
    StringBuilder urlString = new StringBuilder();
    urlString.append("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json");
    urlString.append("?origin=");// from
    urlString.append(Double.toString(sourcelat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString(sourcelog));
    urlString.append("&destination=");// to
    urlString
            .append(Double.toString(destlat));
    urlString.append(",");
    urlString.append(Double.toString(destlog));
    urlString.append("&sensor=false&mode=driving&alternatives=true");
    urlString.append("&key=MyApiKey");
    return urlString.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid Google Maps API web services don't support such kind of bulk operations. You can only send one origin and one destination for Directions API.

Comment: Is there any way to save hits ???? @xomena